# Why is one user able to assign a code review, but another cannot?

Tags: plasticscm

Having upgraded to Plastic SCM version 8.0.16.3533, one user who can assign code reviews, another can't.

The users each have two domain accounts using the same user ID, i.e. domain1\userID and domain2\userID.  I've ensured the users old domain account have been deactivated. They both have active licences and are in a group assigned to the repository permissions.

No code

All users are able to assign code reviews.